# Issue in the alignment of grid row and task row while scrolling vertically to the end of the page

Tags: html, css, dhtmlx

I was working with the DHTML gantt. I had an issue in the alignment of grid row and task row while scrolling vertically to the end of the page. There is a gap between the task row and grid row. The issue exists in the example also. Please check this example: https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/01_basic.html

I am using the same example code in my project.

Expand all the closed trees and scroll the page vertically to the end of the page. The issue screenshot is attached.

[image]

NB: I am just using the tasks. I am not using the task links and milestones.

Comment: Please submit your code here.

Comment: https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/01_basic.html

I am using the same example code in my project.